# Make links to redirected questions display title instead of raw URL (i.e. look pretty)

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, title

A URL that redirects to another question, like this one: <sup>[1]</sup>

[Raise the bar for tags that have been community-deleted, to make it harder for them to return](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207123)

Doesn't resolve the URL to the question title, as can be seen in the question it redirects to:

[Raise the bar for tags that have been community-deleted, to make it harder for them to return](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207123)

Can we change / fix this so it displays the question title as well?

This applies to (special?) MSO to MSE redirection, and seemingly also any other redirection, example:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200511

**Extension:**

The extension of this would be to let links to other SE sites change as well. Example:

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36423

I'm not sure whether I should post a separate feature request for that.

**Motivation:**

If motivation is required, consider that the editing of any post containing such a link (which there are a lot of, considering the MSO/MSE split) will end up making it look less pretty (this resolution only happens during editing, to my knowledge), assuming this isn't changed in the post as well.

And posting links would be easier (in corner cases?).

---

[1]: For those not aware, any URL on Meta SO for a post below a certain ID gets redirected to Meta SE, so the above Meta SO link redirects to Meta SE.

---

(Above displays hard-coded so the value of the question isn't lost if something changes)

Comment: This applies to any link that is external to the specific site (like an external web link, of course, but also just some other network post on SE).

Comment: @Werner I just assumed links to other SE sites change (as a link to MSE from here changes, for some reason), but it indeed doesn't seem to be true. I'm not sure if you're inferring that we should make this work to non-SE sites as well, though there may be reasons why we want to avoid that.

Comment: I was only inferring to make it work for internal links (on the SE network).